# TSQLQuery not returning right amount of records

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have a table called `Artist` which currently contains four records and a `TSQLQuery` that contains the following statement:

```
SELECT name
FROM Artist
```

The table Artist also contains the following records:

```
id          name
1           Artist 1
2           Artist 2
3           Artist 3
4           Artist 4
```

---

**Current method of record retrieval:**

```
Query1.Open;
for i := 0 to qArtist.FieldCount -1 do
    with cbArtist.ListBox.ListItems[i] do
        Text := qArtist.Fields[i].AsString;
```

**Previous method of record retrieval:**

Data bind `Query1` to `ComboBox1`.

---

With the "previous" method, `ComboBox1` would display all the expected records from the `Artist` table. However, when I try to use "current" method `Query1` is only selecting the very first record from the `Artist` table despite there being three other existing values. I have tried the "current" method across other queries and they also returned only the first value of the table.

The reason I am going for this new approach is because I feel that I am very limited in what I can do if I continue to the "previous" / data bind method, but that is besides the point.

So how can I fix this problem? i.e. the problem of the query only selecting the very first record from the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use the [`Eof`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof) and [`Next`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Next) methods to iterate over the records.

```
Query1.Open;
 while not Query1.eof do
 begin
  cbArtist.Items.Add(Query1.FieldByName('Artist').AsString);
  Query1.Next;
 end;
```

Comment: This code is a lot simpler than what I planned to write. Dynamically creating TTabItems for the ComboBox at runtime? What was I thinking ... But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You code show an interaction over fields, if you need iterate all record then you must use a code like:

```
Query1.Open;
Query1.first;
while not Query1.eof do
begin
    with cbArtist.ListBox.ListItems[i] do
        Text := qArtist.Fields[1].AsString; //put here field you want to bind on ListBox.
    Query1.next;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are navigating your query's dataset correctly.  The FieldCount and Fields[i] access the field metadata (columns going across), not the rows.  I beleive in Delphi you use While not Eof begin... end.

[Navigating Datasets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Navigating_Datasets)

I would consider altering the data binding fields to suit your needs.  Delphi's Databinding is very powerful.   Manually iterating the dataset just to populate a control will just be extra code where bugs can hide.   Utilize the built-in capabilities of the tools and it will be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: More a comment than an answer I would say?

Comment: I just don't know how powerful data bindings can be. I'd better start researching then. Thank you for your answer!